# Understanding Calendar time, clarification needed

Tags: java, date, time, calendar

Consider the following snippet

```
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());

    Calendar calendarInstance = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(calendarInstance.getTimeInMillis());

    // Get current
    int year = calendarInstance.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = 1 + calendarInstance.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    calendarInstance.set(year, month, 7 , 19, 00);

    System.out.println(calendarInstance.getTimeInMillis());
```

The first 2 prints are "pretty much now". The 3rd one is **yesterday** at 7pm. Why is the 3rd number the largest?

1. 1,352,389,069,723
2. 1,352,389,069,734
3. 1,354,669,249,734

Correct me if i am wrong, but in a

```
calendarInstance.set(year, month, 7 , 19, 00);
```

We're dealing with `2012, 11, the 7th day, 7 pm`.

What am i missing please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just added 1 month to date. So it's future.

```
int month = 1 + calendarInstance.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

This can be confusing, but I guess you add 1 because of months are 0-index based in Java. Unfortunately.

Comment: +1.  Regardless of whether Calendar months are 0-based or 1-based, there is no reason to assume that this would be different in terms of input or output.  Whatever value you get back should be good to pass back in as "this month"...